# Install External Python Module into Salt Execution Module

Tags: python, salt

I have created a custom module (my_module) that is called via an SLS file in Salt.

Inside of my_module, I use external Python modules.

Do I need to install these external Python modules on the minion or does Salt manage this for any Python modules present in the Salt modules?

If it does need to be managed manually, do I do it in the SLS file via the following:

```
install_my_packages:
pip.installed:
  - names:
    - external_python_module
```